# Running a Setup SQL script with Docker in .NET Core 2 upon container build

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-2.0

I keep seeing how to do this with Entity Framework, but I'm not using EF. I want to run a SQL Setup Script I created which creates the tables and inserts data in the table when I build my docker container that has SQL Server installed. I am using Visual Studio 2017 with .NET Core 2.0.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  dockertest:
    image: dockertest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerTest/Dockerfile

  mssql:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    volumes:
      - mssql:/var/opt/mssql/data/
    container_name: hscarddb
    environment:
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    ports:
      - "5434:1433"

volumes:
   mssql:
```

My DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj DockerTest/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/DockerTest
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

My SQL Setup script:

```
GO
USE master;
GO
CREATE TABLE Sets (Id int NOT NULL, SetName nvarchar(max), PRIMARY KEY (Id));
Go
CREATE TABLE Rarity (Id int NOT NULL, Name nvarchar(max), PRIMARY KEY(Id));
Go
CREATE TABLE Cards (Id int NOT NULL, Name nvarchar(max), ManaCost int, Attack int, Health int, RarityId int, SetsId int
PRIMARY KEY (Id),
FOREIGN KEY (RarityId) REFERENCES Rarity(Id),
FOREIGN KEY (SetsId) REFERENCES Sets(Id));
GO

INSERT INTO Rarity VALUES (1, 'Free');
INSERT INTO Rarity VALUES (2, 'Common');
INSERT INTO Rarity VALUES (3, 'Rare');
INSERT INTO Rarity VALUES (4, 'Epic');
INSERT INTO Rarity VALUES (5, 'Legendary');

INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (1, 'Basic');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (2, 'Classic');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (3, 'Hall of Fame');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (4, 'Curse of Naxxramas');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (5, 'Goblins vs Gnomes');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (6, 'Blackrock Mountain');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (7, 'The Grand Tournament');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (8, 'League of Explorers');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (9, 'Whispers of the Old Gods');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (10, 'One Night in Karazhan');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (11, 'Mean Streets of Gadgetzan');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (12, 'Journey to UnGoro');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (13, 'Knights of the Frozen Throne');
INSERT INTO Sets VALUES (14, 'Kobolds and Catacombs');

INSERT INTO Cards VALUES (1, 'Ragnaros the Firelord', 8, 8, 8, 5, 3);
INSERT INTO Cards VALUES (2, 'Call of the Wild', 9, null, null, 4, 11);
INSERT INTO Cards VALUES (3, 'Corridor Creeper', 7, 5, 5, 4, 14);
```

Basically when I build my app, I want it to build the database container, run the SQL script on it, and then run my application against it (which is just a simple proof of concept API).

I think I need to add something in the DockerFile to be able to run my setup.sql but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a custom mssql image and add the sql script when building the image?

I'm currently using the following solution. Somewhere in your 'mssql'-dockerfile should be:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/scripts
COPY database.sql /opt/scripts

ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 10 \
&& /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'P@ssw0rd' -i /opt/scripts/database.sql \
&& pkill sqlservr
```

Don't forget to put a database.sql (with your script) next to the dockerfile, as that is copied into the image.